# ftp create a log for every file sent

Tags: linux, unix, ftp

im looking to create an ftp log for every file that has been sent. I have already developed the ftp and it creates a log but get overwritten every time a file has been sent. this is my solution below but it is not working. anyone any ideas ?

```
export ftplog=$datestamp.ftplog

#Find files produced and re-name
  cd $files

  for i in $(ls *.csv 2>/dev/null)
   do
        mv -f $i $archive/ESS09651.$i

        ftp -vn $ftphostname >> $ftp/$ftplog 2>&1 << EOF
        quote USER $username
        quote PASS $password
        put $archive/ESS09651.$i ESS09651.$i
        bye
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code appends the log file (`>>`). It should not not overwrite it.

---

Anyway, if you want to create a separate log file for each uploaded file, use filename as a part of a log file name:

```
ftp -vn $ftphostname >> $ftp/$datestamp.$i.ftplog 2>&1 << EOF
```